# How do I keep leading zeroes when extracting day and month from date

Tags: sql, hive

I have dates that look so

```
2017-02-22
2017-02-23
2017-02-05
```

I need to extract dates in this format dd.mm, so it looks so

```
23.02
22.02
05.02
```

but this

```
concat(day(PLAN_REPAYMENT_DATE_KEY), '.', month(PLAN_REPAYMENT_DATE_KEY))
```

returns

```
23.2
22.2
5.2
```

How do I keep the leading zeroes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. date_format(PLAN_REPAYMENT_DATE_KEY,'dd.MM') 
2. from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(PLAN_REPAYMENT_DATE_KEY),'dd.MM')
3. printf('%02d.%02d',day(PLAN_REPAYMENT_DATE_KEY),month(PLAN_REPAYMENT_DATE_KEY))
```

---

```
hive> with t as (select date '2017-02-05' as PLAN_REPAYMENT_DATE_KEY)
    > select date_format(PLAN_REPAYMENT_DATE_KEY,'dd.MM') from t;
OK
05.02
```

---

```
hive> with t as (select date '2017-02-05' as PLAN_REPAYMENT_DATE_KEY) 
    > select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(PLAN_REPAYMENT_DATE_KEY),'dd.MM') from t;
OK
05.02
```

---

```
hive> with t as (select date '2017-02-05' as PLAN_REPAYMENT_DATE_KEY)
    > select printf('%02d.%02d',day(PLAN_REPAYMENT_DATE_KEY),month(PLAN_REPAYMENT_DATE_KEY)) from t;
OK
05.02
```

Answer (score 0):

```
concat(LPAD(day(PLAN_REPAYMENT_DATE_KEY), 2, '0'), '.', LPAD(MONTH(PLAN_REPAYMENT_DATE_KEY), 2, '0'))
```

edit: added LPAD to day as well.

Comment: The day should also be padded

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz that's true ; )